# How to draw behind an image in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, canvas

I am using canvas for a picture crop feature and I cannot figure out how to fill the empty spaces.

First, this is what I'm doing:

Canvas element:

```
   <canvas
     id="previewCanvas"
     ref={previewCanvasRef}
     style={{
     border: '1px solid black',
     objectFit: 'contain',
     width: '300px',
     height: '300px',
     }}
  />
```

This is the function I use to draw the image:

```
const TO_RADIANS = Math.PI / 180;

export async function canvasPreview(image, canvas, crop, scale = 1, rotate = 0) {
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  if (!ctx) {
    throw new Error('No 2d context');
  }

  const scaleX = image.naturalWidth / image.width;
  const scaleY = image.naturalHeight / image.height;
  // devicePixelRatio slightly increases sharpness on retina devices
  // at the expense of slightly slower render times and needing to
  // size the image back down if you want to download/upload and be
  // true to the images natural size.
  const pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio;
  // const pixelRatio = 1

  canvas.width = Math.floor(crop.width * scaleX * pixelRatio);
  canvas.height = Math.floor(crop.height * scaleY * pixelRatio);

  ctx.scale(pixelRatio, pixelRatio);
  ctx.imageSmoothingQuality = 'high';

  const cropX = crop.x * scaleX;
  const cropY = crop.y * scaleY;

  const rotateRads = rotate * TO_RADIANS;
  const centerX = image.naturalWidth / 2;
  const centerY = image.naturalHeight / 2;

  ctx.save();

  // 5) Move the crop origin to the canvas origin (0,0)
  ctx.translate(-cropX, -cropY);
  // 4) Move the origin to the center of the original position
  ctx.translate(centerX, centerY);
  // 3) Rotate around the origin
  ctx.rotate(rotateRads);
  // 2) Scale the image
  ctx.scale(scale, scale);
  // 1) Move the center of the image to the origin (0,0)
  ctx.translate(-centerX, -centerY);
  ctx.drawImage(
    image,
    0,
    0,
    image.naturalWidth,
    image.naturalHeight,
    0,
    0,
    image.naturalWidth,
    image.naturalHeight
  );

  ctx.restore();
}
```

This is how I see the canvas on the browser:
[image]

Now, when I convert the image to a blob, then to a file object, I get an image like this :
[image]

What I expect to happen is to get an image like this: (exactly like in the preview)
[image]

What am I doing wrong ?